# Ok I used all my votes... now what?

Tags: discussion, area-51, voting

I'm following a few proposals and it seems like after about 5 minutes of reading example questions I've already used all of my votes. What is there to do after that on a proposal? Sit and wait?

Comment: Post on Meta to ask for more votes? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can round up followers from other sites, if you like. Other than that, you've done all you can. It's up to other people to follow, contribute, and vote to make the site a reality.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out new questions that come in, and change your vote if they are better on or off-topic questions.